# Inserting the value of the variable into the database through python

Tags: python, database, insert

I am new to Python, so need some help in this concern:
Here I am trying to insert the values in the database, when I tried giving the hard coded values then insertion taking place,

Note: common_test2 has only 2 words

But when I am writing like below:

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('sys/sys@127.0.0.1:1599/xe')
print(con.version) //just to check the connection
print("this connection is established") //connection is tested
cur=con.cursor()

f3= open("common_test2", 'r+')
string= f3.read()
common_words=string.split()
x=common_words[0]
y=common_words[1]
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(name,id) VALUES (%s,%d)", ('hello',30))
con.commit()
```

Error is
**Error is cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number**

Also tried `cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(name,id) VALUES (x, y)")`
but no luck 
Error is **cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00984: column not allowed here**

Any help?

```
#I am using this for updating the table
y=100%
x=text
cur.execute("update temp set perc=(:1)", (y))
#Please note: I only want 100 to be updated in the table not the % (only 100 as numeric)
cur.execute("update temp set remarks=(:1)",(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Error comes from here:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(name,id) VALUES (%s,%d)", ('hello',30))
```

Try to use `:n` pointers:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(name, id) VALUES (:1, :2)", ('hello', 30))
```

---

#### update

For your second case - if `y` is a string like `y = "100%"`, then you can make update this way:

```
cur.execute("update temp set perc = :1", (y[:-1],))
```

This will insert `100` as an `int`.
Note that 1-item sized tuple is `(x,)`, **not** `(x)`.

#### Code I'm Using

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect('system/system@127.0.0.1:1521/xe')

# print(con.version)
# 
# print("this connection is established")

cur = con.cursor()

f3 = open("common.txt", 'r+') #this text file have only 2 words lets say (10% increased)

string = f3.read() #will read common.txt

common_words = string.split() 

x = common_words[0]     #here x have 10%

y = common_words[1]     #here y have increased

# Now I want 10 should be updated in the temp table **Not 10%** 

cur.execute("update temp set perc=(:1)", (y[:-1],))
cur.execute("update temp set remarks=(:1)", (y))

con.commit
```

Note: I have to retrieve that 10 and do further calculations

Table Temp:

perc    remarks

10      increased

Comment: Tried as per your suggestions but error 
**cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number**

Comment: can you help me with the dynamic update command 

y=100%

cur.execute("update temp set perc=(:1)", (y))

Note: I want only 100 should be entered not with '%'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add this code to your question and I will update my answer.

Comment: Tried the same, getting this error:

cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data type tuple

Comment: Please don't use "UPDATE" blocks. People coming here in the future don't care about the edit history of the post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post/127655#127655